# Join two table in PostgreSQL where one content Array field and other is a master table of that array field

Tags: database, postgresql, go

I'm new in PostgreSQL and I have one query in my mind. Suppose there are two tables, one is Fruit which have FruitID (text) and FruitName (text) fields. Another is Food table where a field called Fruit which is  string array type and contains FruitID. Is there any query in PostgreSQL where by joining two tables we can get all data from Food table with fruit name array instead of fruit id array?

```
Select * from Fruit

id|Name
--|-----
A1|Mango     
A2|Orange   
A3|Banana 


Select * from Food

id|Day     |Fruit
--|--------|-------
A1|Sunday  |{A1,A2}   
A2|Monday  |{A2,A3}   
A3|Tuesday |{A1,A3}
```

My output should be like that after join two table:

```
id|Day     |Fruit Name
--|--------|--------------
A1|Sunday  |{Mango,Orange}   
A2|Monday  |{Orange,Banana}
A3|Tuesday |{Mango,Banana}
```

Comment: Ok wait some minuits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expand the `Food` table's `FruitId` into rows, join those to the `Fruit` table, and then use `array_agg()` to aggregate the expanded rows.

```
=# select * from fruit;

 fruitid | fruitname 
---------+-----------
 app     | apple
 ban     | banana
 grp     | grape
 ora     | orange
(4 rows)

=# select * from food;

 id |     fruit     
----+---------------
  1 | {app,grp}
  2 | {app,ban,grp}
(2 rows)

=# with expand as (
  select id, unnest(fruit) as FruitId 
    from food
), lookup as (
   select e.id, f.FruitName 
     from expand e
     join fruit f on f.FruitId = e.FruitId
)
select id, array_agg(FruitName) as FruitNames
  from lookup
 group by id;

 id |      fruitnames       
----+----------------------
  2 | {apple,banana,grape}
  1 | {apple,grape}
(2 rows)
```

Adjusting to the schema you added to your question:

```
with expand as (
  select id, day, unnest(fruit) as fruitid
    from food
), lookup as (
  select e.id, e.day, f.name as fruitname
    from expand e
    join fruit f on f.id = e.fruitid
)
select id, day as "Day", array_agg(fruitname) as "Fruit Name"
  from lookup
 group by id, day
 order by id;

 id |   Day   |   Fruit Name    
----+---------+-----------------
 A1 | Sunday  | {Mango,Orange}
 A2 | Monday  | {Orange,Banana}
 A3 | Tuesday | {Mango,Banana}
(3 rows)
```

Comment: I am happy to have been of help.  If your life was truly at risk, perhaps you should consider adding more fruit varieties to your diet?  I recommend grapes and apples from my original example along with strawberries :-)